# Right to Left Writing Using English Letters

Tags: microsoft-word

Can you write your name from right to left using English characters in micrsoft word 2007. For example if your name is zaid it shoud appear as diaz by typing z, a ,i and d respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Windows (so i can't provide detailed instructions), but from my last job supporting Israeli consultants i remember that there *are* several right-to-left text options in Word, but they are only accessible when a right-to-left language is enabled.

So, if you add (for example) Hebrew to your input languages in Regional and Language Options (or whatever it's called now), you should find a button on the Word tool bar that will do what you want.